# GIT branch with code from multiple repositories

Tags: git, meta

Is there a way to create a branch which contains code from multiple repositories. For example
in Repo 1, I've code 1, and code 2
in Repo 2, I've code 3, code 4, and code 5.

Can I create a development branch with code 1 from Repo 1 and code 3 and code 5 from Repo 2?

I've come across meta plugin for GIT. But, it allows you to add multiple repositories (entire repositories) to a branch.

Comment: I guess you can't just import some parts of repository into another repository. Usually it is done via git submodules. You export part of the repository into separate repository (there are plenty description of how to do that, just search for `git submodule`), and then use it as submodule in your main repository (or in others). Then, you could have your shared code in separate repo, and just include it to your others repositories as submodule.

Comment: Sub modules is likely the answer. You cannot do this in a single repo because a branch is just a reference to a specific commit (with some logic when creating a child commit). And a single commit is either in a remote or not in a remote, it can't be partly in one and partly in another.

Comment: Did you already have had a look at Google's [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/) for managing multiple repositories?